# Outlining a path looks ugly at the start/end of the path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, path

I have a closed path. The corner where I started and ended the path looks like this:

[image]

When I do `Object > Path > Outline Stroke`, that corner is not perfectly outlined. Sometimes I can see the details.

[image]

This is how the anchor points look:

[image]

Looks like the path wasn't broken. I would like the start and end do not notice. Is it an Illustrator limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Look like you may have an additional stroke applied to the top image via the appearance panel, it's thicker. Do you?

Comment: Yes I do, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have additional strokes applied via the appearance panel, the Outline Stroke command is not what you want to use. The Outline Stroke command will use the base stroke and ignore any appearance items. You first need to apply or "burn in" the appearance items.

- Select the shape
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` (Converts appearance strokes and fills to actual objects)
- Choose `Object > Expand` (Converts strokes to shapes)
- Click the **Merge** or **Unite** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Combines everything into one shape)

This will leave you with a single shape which matches the outline of your multiple strokes *plus* the appearance stroke.

Comment: Uhh, the `Object > Expand Appearance` causes the same effect as `Outline Stroke`. I have to fix manually corner by corner.

Comment: @Kiewic can you link to a sample file?